The links in the quick links web part were suddenly changed to random links of pages from the same site collection. what is triggering this?
The links in the quick links web part were suddenly changed to random links of pages from the same site collection. what is triggering this?
Apart from that there were missing page authors/owners. Instead of the right owners, the contact on the top was substituted with our general SharePoint email/user.
